# Unable to shift values under one header to another

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, data-manipulation

I'm trying to swap values between two cells under the headers `Title` and `Name` in a csv file based on a condition. I get success when the headers are like:

`Organization` `Working since` `Gender` `Title` `Name`  `ID`

However, when they are like the following (`multiple headers having the same set of names`) I get stuck:

`Organization` `Working since` `Gender` `Title` `Name` `ID`  `Title` `Name` `ID`

> What I'm trying to do is check whether the header `Title` contains any value but `Name` doesn't. If that is true then the content under the header `Title` will be shifted to `Name`. However, if the content under the header `Name` has already any value then leave them as they are.

I've tried with (works when there is a single set of header):

```
import csv

with open('profile_info.csv', 'r') as infile, open('modified.csv', 'w', newline="") as outfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(infile)
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=['Title','Name','ID'])
    writer.writeheader()
    for row in reader:
        if not row['Name']:
            row['Name'] = row['Title']

            """I don't know any better option for the following line"""

            row['Title']= ""
        else:
            row['Title'],row['Name']
        writer.writerow(row)
        print(row['Title'],row['Name'])
```

***[Image](https://filebin.net/c5rtovlf6tuccci7)*** of `profile_info.csv` file.

***[Image](https://filebin.net/cicda5nrdthwc47n)*** of `modified.csv` file.

If you wanna test yourself, this is the ***[main csv](https://filebin.net/86o9885j103ddgsm)*** file for your convenience.

Comment: Given header as `Title Name ID Title Name ID` then you can't use `DictReader`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution does not require any special packages. It simply reads the first row of the `CSV` file and renames the offending columns and passes the renamed columns to the `cvs.DictReader` call.

```
import csv

with open('profile_info.csv', 'r') as infile, open('modified.csv', 'w', newline="") as outfile:
    # read bad column names to get rid of it
    infile.readline()
    # new column names:
    column_names = ['Organization', 'Working since', 'Gender', 'Title', 'Name', 'ID', 'Title_1', 'Name_1', 'ID_1']
    reader = csv.DictReader(infile, fieldnames=column_names) # supply modified column names
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=column_names)
    writer.writeheader()
    for row in reader:
        if not row['Name']:
            row['Name'] = row['Title']
            row['Title']= ""
        if not row['Name_1']:
            row['Name_1'] = row['Title_1']
            row['Title_1']= ""
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: I tried your solution just now. The first headers  'Name` gets the values accordingly but the second `Name_1` headers remains unchanged whereas these two names `Sajal` and `Jimmi` are supposed to be shifted from `Title_1` to `Name_1`. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry about that. I thought your sole issue was the presence of of duplicated column names, which I handled by renaming. I didn't realize you needed to shift those `Title_1` and `Name_1`columns, too. I have updated the solution.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use DictReader when there are duplicate headers. What you can do is fallback to csv.reader and have your logic for assigning the value.

I find using pandas and numpy lot easier (if you have the liberty to install these packages).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("profile.csv")

#handling the second 'Name' and 'Title' header
df['Name.2'] = np.where(df['Name.1'].isna(), df['Title.1'], df['Name.1'])
df['Title.1'] = np.where(df['Name.1'].isna(), "", df['Title.1'])

#handling the first 'Name' and 'Title' header
df['Name.3'] = np.where(df['Name'].isna(), df['Title'], df['Name'])
df['Title'] = np.where(df['Name'].isna(), "", df['Title'])

# Drop the old columns, since we have new ones in 'Name.2' and 'Name.3'
df.drop(['Name.1','Name'], inplace=True, axis=1)

# Rearranging the columns to match modified.csv
df = df[['Organization', 'Working since', 'Gender', 'Title', 'Name.3','ID','Title.1','ID.1','Name.2']]

# Rename columns to match modified.csv
df.rename(columns={'Name.2':'Name', 'Name.3': 'Name', 'Title.1':'Title', 'ID.1':'ID'}, inplace=True)
df.to_csv("modified.csv", index=False)
```

pandas can identify duplicate headers and adds a suffix to them, making it easy to modify the columns.

Comment: Your suggested approach looks cleaner. I tried it but found that it is only changing the content under second set of headers. However, the content under the first targeted headers are still as it was. See the ***[image](https://filebin.net/e9cqcp06srbtxbjv)*** for the clarity. The arrows in the image pointed at the desired location.

Comment: @robots.txt Updated the solution to handle the first Name and Title, Sorry I missed that the first time. The approach is similar, I have created new columns from the existing one and renamed them to match the output.

Comment: Please use `#` for comments in python.